# SharePoint download/upload file as stream using Powershell Get-PnPFile and Add-PnPFile

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to download file from source SharePoint site using

```
    $fileSource = Get-PnPFile -Url $filePath -AsFileObject -Connection $sourceConnection
```

But how to upload the file to another SharePoint site using the returned $fileSource

```
    $fileDest = Add-PnPFile -FileName $filename -Folder "uploadFolder" -Stream <what goes here?> -Connection $destConnection
```

I tried

```
    $fileDest = Add-PnPFile -FileName $filename -Folder "uploadFolder" -Stream $fileSource -Connection $destConnection
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any update ? Did the code get the file stream and use in Add-PnPFile command, please share the update if possible..

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload file with file stream like this:

```
$Username='user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
$Password = 'yourpwd'
 
#region Credentials
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials
 
#connect to hubsite
Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://Teant.sharepoint.com/' -Credentials $PSCredentials
$sourceConnection=Get-PnPConnection
$filePath="/Shared Documents/test.jpg"
$filename="test.jpg"
$fileSource = (Get-PnPFile -Url $filePath -AsFileObject -Connection $sourceConnection).OpenBinaryStream()
Invoke-PnPQuery
$stream = $fileSource.Value
$fileDest = Add-PnPFile -FileName $filename -Folder "/Shared Documents/2019" -Stream  $stream -Connection $sourceConnection
```

The stream value is got from the lines:

```
$fileSource = (Get-PnPFile -Url $filePath -AsFileObject -Connection $sourceConnection).OpenBinaryStream()
Invoke-PnPQuery
$stream = $fileSource.Value
```

Comment: That works fine. But I want to use stream to see whether it could improve the performance. I have close to one million files to migrate.

Comment: @user3616544, please check the updated answer, it will get the file stream as expected :)